# ¿como se puede validar si un documento pdf es malicioso en c# mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, pdf, seguridad

La necesidad es como evitar el cargue de documentos maliciosos a mi aplicación en MVC5, de manera que pueda verificar y determinar si es potencialmente dañino, para ejemplo estoy utilizando un documento de este [articulo](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2015/08/28/test-file-pdf-with-embedded-doc-dropping-eicar/) el cual tiene modificaciones y ejecuta codigo script VBA, ejecutandose al abrir el documento.

Si hay una API para validar un PDF o como en codigo lo podría manejar evitando este fallo de seguridad.

Mcuhas gracias, por la ayuda.

Comment: Es muy dificil detectar un documento malicioso, un documento danado no es lo mismo que malicioso, para detectar documentos mailiciosos es mejor usar un software especializado

Comment: @MiguelZarate ¿conoces alguno?

Comment: puedes implementar una api mediante https://github.com/Genbox/VirusTotalNet

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias @MiguelZarate la revisaré y comentaré el resultado.